# Orthogonality Relations for Character Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, characters

I'm trying to understand a part of a proof of orthogonality relations for character groups and finite abelian groups, and I don't quite get this part from the below link:

http://www.ms.uky.edu/~pkoester/research/charactersums.pdf

In 2.3, Proposition 10, it is given that χ is not equal to χ_0. What exactly does it mean for a character to not be equal to another? Does this mean they are two different homomorphisms? For Proposition 10, is χ a fixed homomorphism in the character group of G?

How do they reach the conclusion that (χ(y) − 1), summation of (χ(y) − 1)χ(x) for every x in G = 0?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Using x in G and z in G is the same thing, so they just subtracted on both sides, resulting in the above. Sorry I have no idea how to use Latex and the above is horribly formatted.